# Laravel Limit Results by Many-Many Relationship

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set up a view specifically for a user that limits their data to display only doctors that were assigned to them via a many-many relationship. Here is the original code:

```
$doctors = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->orderBy($sortBy, $sort)
    ->paginate(10);
```

This worked just fine. However, I recently added search functionality that looks like this:

```
// search default
if ($request->search == null) {
    $search = '';
} else {
    $search = $request->search;
}

$doctors = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->orderBy($sortBy, $sort)
    ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('npi', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('license', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('dea', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Now when I look at it from the rep's point of view, it shows all of the doctors in the database. I'm assuming that making the `$search` return '', it is overriding the User->doctors() request. How can I keep the search functionality but make sure and limit the doctors to those that are attributed only to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the `orWhere` clauses, otherwise your getting all doctors associated with the user **and** where the `first_name` is like `$search` **OR** where the `last_name` is like `$search` on **all** doctors.

try this:

```
 $doctors = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
        ->doctors()
        ->orderBy($sortBy, $sort)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('npi', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('license', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('dea', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use when and group where

```
$search = $request->input('search');

$doctors = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->when($search, function($query) use ($search){
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query
                ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('npi', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('license', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('dea', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
    })
    ->orderBy('...')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Yes, looked at my sources - where grouping required. Corrected.

Comment: @IndianCoding To make sure I am fully understanding this code, the `when` clause will essentially replace my `if` check to see if a search query has been submitted?